# My western Digital hard disk was failed to be recognized by Ubuntu system recently. It seems have error sectors. How to recover data from it?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, data-recovery

I have a 6T internal hard drive in my Desktop with Ubuntu 20.0.4 system. It works well before, but very recently it happened twice that it can't be recognized by the system (unmounted). The first time it happened, I re-boosted the PC several times and the HDD showed up in the system finally. But the 2nd time it happens, re-boosting does not work at all.

I also tried external desktop drive reader but still does not work. I can see this disk in the disk list when open "disk" function under ubuntu, but it is unmounted. See picture below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mynYo.png)

I also used smartctl tool to make disk analysis, here is the results:

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdc
smartctl 7.2 2020-12-30 r5155 [x86_64-linux-6.2.0-26-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-20, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Red
Device Model:     WDC WD60EFRX-68MYMN1
Serial Number:    WD-WXL1H84DWLHK
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 260be9614
Firmware Version: 82.00A82
User Capacity:    6,001,175,126,016 bytes [6.00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5700 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 3b
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Jan 18 13:13:03 2024 PST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        ( 7004) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 723) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x303d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   196   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   206   202   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       8683
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       164
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   004   004   000    Old_age   Always       -       70540
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       164
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       158
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   179   179   000    Old_age   Always       -       65008
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   129   106   000    Old_age   Always       -       23
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       22
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 1
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 1 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 5002 hours (208 days + 10 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 01 00 00 00 40  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x00000000 = 0

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  40 00 01 00 00 00 40 00      00:03:44.379  READ VERIFY SECTOR(S)
  ef 10 02 00 00 00 00 00      00:03:44.127  SET FEATURES [Enable SATA feature]
  ef 02 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:03:44.127  SET FEATURES [Enable write cache]
  ef aa 00 00 00 00 00 00      00:03:44.127  SET FEATURES [Enable read look-ahead]
  ef 03 46 00 00 00 00 00      00:03:44.127  SET FEATURES [Set transfer mode]

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

So, I would love to have any suggestion on how to make this disk to be recognized by the system and recover data on it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

clone disk with ``dd''

```
 sudo dd if=/dev/sdc of=/tmp/disk.img bs=8M status=progress oflag=direct
```

install foremost file recovering

```
sudo apt install foremost
```

run foremost on disk image and save files found to directory with `-o' option

```
foremost -o /tmp/formost/ -v -t all /tmp/disk.img
```

Comment: Adding some explanation to your answer would seriously improve it.

Comment: also the first command copies data from a file to a disk, it should be the other way round.

Comment: Thank you so much for you suggestion, petep! I did tried your code with a little modification suggested by AndyTheEntity. It seems that "dd" function stopped copying data after creating a ~87G .img file, so I used another function "ddrescue", this one make a disk.img file  ~4T before it stuck, as I have totally 5T data in my 6T HDD. Then, I run "foremost" and only saved 2G files from it, and also with original file names lost. I can't believe why a 4T disk.image can only saved 2G files? Any suggestions? So disappointed so far.

Comment: ddrescue was a good choice. After carefully saving everything you have recovered, you might want to try running ddrescue with a mapping file several more times with cool-down time between and see if it reads more sectors.  Once you have gotten all you can (or the drive totally dies), try a variety of recovery tools on the img file. Some may be better at recovering some types of data errors than others. Also search for mounting an img file as it could be possible. [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) for info on mapping file and more if you haven't read all the fine points.

Answer (score 0):

**With a pretty big caveat emptor. Especially if this is a failing hardware issue.**

It might be worth giving `testdisk` a try? The method I follow is from [It's Foss](https://itsfoss.com/recover-deleted-files-linux/) and deals with recovering deleted files. Your steps (if Testdisk can see the drive at all) will look a little different.

I have only used it to recover accidentally deleted files on *working* external hard-drives and SD-cards, but it does also have the capacity to help retrieve files from unbootable, corrupted drives, and the article gives a few pointers in that direction too.

**To install**

`sudo apt install testdisk`

**and run**

`testdisk`

Testdisk is run entirely from the terminal, with no gui component. So it's worth unplugging other hard-drives to make it easier for you to find what you're looking for, but you do need to read carefully at each step the information they give you.